# Classpath in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

When i use **class-path attribute** in spring XML file as below,

```
<bean class="com.fritolay.suppliernet.common.lastresorthandler.impl.SingletonPropertiesRepository">
<property name="propertiesFile" value="classpath:ecr/sample.properties" />
</bean>
```

**In this case where does the server looks for properties file in application?**

My question is that i have two modules[1.Web Project 2.Java Project]. I am defining this XML file in web project and placing properties files under java project src folder.But when i deploy my application i am getting following error:

```
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'propertiesFile' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ecr/sample.properties] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: zip:C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/sample/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_supplier-net_ear/6e86rt/sample-service.jar!/ecr/sample.properties
```

Comment: Is the properties file in the `ecr` package? Does the bean itself handle classpath resources?

Comment: Yes the properties file is in ecr package.Yes in the bean class its handling resource file as below.                                              public void setPropertiesFile(Resource propertiesFile) throws IOException {
        this.repository.setPropertiesFiles(Collections.singletonMap(
                DEFAULT_KEY, propertiesFile));
    }

Comment: Have you checked the properties files are being deployed at the /WEB-INF/classes directory, or inside the JAR file where your classes are being packed (in case they are)?

Comment: @Tomas: I checked the properties file exists in the location where it is referring.In this case it's inside jar folder sample-service.jar/ecr.

Comment: But look at the "!" mark. it is looking for the file inside a JAR file, not in a folder. you should check inside the file C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/sample/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_supplier-net_ear/6e86rt/sample-service.jar .

Comment: Hi, Yes my file was inside that jar with in a folder /ecr.I don't understand what the symbol(!) stands for.

Comment: @Prathap as far as I know, the exclamation mark is used to tell that a resource is packed inside a JAR file (not a directory). Please, read my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java engine is looking for your file at this location (read at your error):

```
C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/sample/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_supplier-net_ear/6e86rt/sample-service.jar!/ecr/sample.properties
```

As you can see, the `!` mark implies it is looking for your file inside a temporary JAR file (for sure, an IDE artifact).

It seems that your IDE (or the tool you have chosen for deployment) is not including your properties files inside the JAR, and thus the error.
It may be because of:

- At compilation time, your tool is not copying these recources to the
  compilation target directory (usualy `/classes`)
- At packing time, your JAR building tool is not including the
  `properties` resources into the Jar, avoiding them.

In both cases, to fix it you must check your building and deployment configuration, depending on which IDE or tools you are using.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two different projects, you need to be sure that when you deploy your **web project**, you can access to the code in your **java project**. If you are working in a exploded way you need to give access to your **java project** from your **web project**, in eclipse is easy to do.

Comment: Thanks,Actually i want to deploy/build this application with out eclipse.In eclipse i know we can 'AddProject" dependency easily.

Comment: Then, before to fight with the spring configuration, test if you have the **sample.properties** in the jar that you are generating (or out), but in the ecr folder within WEB-INF. My eclipse advise was if you was working in an exploded manner.